# Getting all records where association count is lower than a column value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models:

```
class Dish
  # column maximum_portions:int

  has_many :portions
end

class Portion
  belongs_to :dish
end
```

What I need is to get all dishes that has less portions than maximum portions.

I tried with group by and having, but nothing works.

Can you help me, please? :)

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dish.left_join(:portions)
    .group("dishes.id")
    .having("COUNT(portions.id) < dishes.maximum_portions")
```

Use left_join if you want dishes with 0 portions and join (which produces a INNER JOIN) with at least 1 portion.

PS: next time, provide sample data to make things easier ;)